# How to position a view right above the keyboard?

Tags: user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm writing a Forms app. How to position a view right at the bottom of the screen and when some entry is focused and the keyboard is visible, the view to be right above the keyboard? On android, it is possible to set `Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize)` and that will make the `Content` resize every time the keyboard is appearing/disappearing. However, I need the status bar to be transparent and `SoftInput.AdjustResize` doesn't work with `WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus`. My question is, how do I position a view right above the keyboard without setting `SoftInput.AdjustResize`?

Take this example:

```
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var al = new StackLayout
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        var button = new BoxView {Color = Color.Red, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand};

        var entry = new Entry {HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill};


        al.Children.Add(entry);

        al.Children.Add(button);

        Content = al;

        Content.SizeChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            button.Layout(new Rectangle(0, Content.Height - 120, App.Dimensions.Width, 120));
        };

    }
```

If you run this code, when you'll press the input, nothing will change, the "button" will remain on the bottom of the screen not visible because of the overlaying keyboard.

If we add `Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize)` in MainActivity's onCreate it works fine, the box is moved above the keyboard on entry's focus.

Also, if we change `Content = al;` to `Content = new ScrollView {Content = al};`, it works fine.

However, if we add `Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);` in MainActivity's onCreate, none of those methods work anymore.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use the KeyboardOverlap plugin https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Forms.KeyboardOverlap/

Comment: Try something like SoftInput.AdjustPan

Comment: adjust pan won't change anything. first link has nothing to do with android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm writing a Forms app. How to position a view right at the bottom of
>   the screen and when some entry is focused and the keyboard is visible,
>   the view to be right above the keyboard?

If you are using Xamarin Forms, then wrapping your UI elements in a ScrollView should do the trick.  Something like this if you are using XAML:

```
<ScrollView>
    <ScrollView.Content>
        //  Your Original XAML content here
    </ScrollView.Content>
<ScrollView
```

EDIT:

Looking at the example you just added, I THINK I know what is happening.  So, the ScrollView Trick only works for elements that require keyboard input.  I.e if you instead had an entry element at the bottom of the screen, and wrapped everything in a ScrollView like I suggested, then the keyboard should push the entry element up for you.  However in your case you have a boxview at the bottom of the screen, which the keyboard simply runs over.

What you have for Content.SizedChanged is a good idea, however I don't think the size of the view actually changes when the keyboard pops up (at least, Content.SizeChanged isn't called when the keyboard pops up), so that part of your code is really only called on loading of the page from the MCVE you provided.

HOWEVER, I was able to move the 'button' up when the keyboard appears by doing this:

Replace

```
Content.SizeChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    button.Layout(new Rectangle(0, Content.Height - 120, App.Dimensions.Width, 120));
};
```

With

```
entry.Focused += (sender, e) => 
{
    button.TranslationY -= 120;
};
```

You may have a heck of a time getting that magic translation number for all the different devices and orientations though.  When I tested it on the iPhone 6 simulator I had to push way above 120 before I could see it above the keyboard.

Hope that helps!

Comment: but that makes my page scrollable in case it doesn't fit the screen. i'm using absolutelayout and sometimes i hide view by sliding them out of the visible area.

Comment: plus for some reason it doesn't work with `WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus`. it's starting to look stupid.

Comment: I'd like to help further but I think at this point I need a minimum, complete, verifiable example (MCVE).  Without one I'll just be guessing at what may fix your issues.

I WILL say that if you can instead format your AbsoluteLayout to fit the screen exactly ('FillAndExpand'), and then instead of sliding views out of the visible area you just set IsVisible to be false on them, you should be close to working.  Are you trying to get some sort of [action tray](https://components.xamarin.com/view/actiontray) feature?

Without a MCVE it's really difficult for me to know what will work for you.

Comment: i **need** sliding for animation. see the edit for MCVE.

Comment: what are your thoughts?

Comment: the problem is that i cannot know how big is the keyboard exactly. if i knew that, there wouldn't be any problem at all. any other thoughts?

Comment: btw, as i said, ScrollView works, but only when i don't set `Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus)` which is weird.

Comment: `Content.SizeChanged` will be called when the keyboard pops up if `Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize)` is set.

Comment: But that is an Android only feature and you are writing a Xamarin.Forms app, right?  You may need to implement a custom renderer if you can't get it to work the way you want by wrapping it in a ScrollView.

Comment: Custom renderer of what exactly?

Comment: Well, if you are doing platform specific things and still want to use XF then, depending on exactly what those platform specific needs are, you may want to consider implementing custom renderers for the view so that you can do special things for each platform.  In your MCVE you didn't include the window flags.

Otherwise, I don't think you can get the keyboard height through XF, but you may be able to do it with the 'native' side of things.  If that's the case then you may be able to simply utilize the DependencyService to write a method to get the keyboard height

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122848/discussion-between-jacob-shanley-and-nika-gamkrelidze).